# Craft CSRF protection and Facebook Tab

Tags: csrf, post

I have a Craft 3 installation and want to add a tab/app to Facebook like domain.com/facebook

Facebook sends a post request to the configured secure tab URL. Now when Craft's CSRF protection is enabled, Craft gives an error. If I disable CSRF protection the tab shows up in Facebook.

I don't want to disable CSRF - what could i do... plugin with a controller to render the template?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the token for a certain controller via

```php
use Craft;
...
Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

or inside a Controller for a certain request

```php
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'my-method') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Take a look at [$enableCsrfValidation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#$enableCsrfValidation-detail) property of [yii\web\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the CSRF protection by event

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\ActionEvent;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\web\Controller;

Event::on(Controller::class, Controller::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION, function (ActionEvent $actionEvent) {
    if ($actionEvent->action->id == 'facebook') {
        Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }
});
```